# How to fix mac version of android eclips 'Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'?

Tags: android, styles, android-appcompat

When compiling I get the error: "Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'". What should the path be in project.properties on a mac? The code works fine on a Windows computer...

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  <-- Error at line 7
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have AppCompat imported into the workspace and referenced as a library project. You can get it from the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: I have all the necessary libraries imported, the thing I read elsewhere is that on a mac it needs to be a relative instead of an absolute path. But I have no idea what to put there. This is what it says now: # Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7

Comment: Open the Properties for the project and add the library project that way. It will set the path automatically.